# Export leaflet in png after having zoomed or moved the map

Tags: r

I draw a classical leaflet map, in R.
After moving or zooming the map, I wish to export it in PNG with `mapview::mapshot`.
I'd like to export the newly zoomed map, not the original location.
The export doesn't integrate the changes I did manually by drag-dropping

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%  
  setView(7.728,48.591,zoom = 17) 
# I move and zoom manually the map
mapshot(m, file = "dreal.jpg")
```

The PNG fig shows my original location, even if I zoomed all France, or moved to New Zealand.

Comment: Have you assign your map to m? `library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
m <-leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%  
  setView(7.728,48.591,zoom = 17) 
# I move and zoom manually the map
mapshot(m, file = "dreal.jpg")`

Comment: Yes, of couse. Oh, sorry I miscopied my code !

Comment: m <-leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%  
  setView(7.728,48.591,zoom = 17)

Comment: and then print(m)